# Landscape ANT is gone

Tags: mesh, add-on

After dealing with an add on named ANT Landscape, present but not operational, meaning I could see it and click on it but nothing would happen, and today it was gone, not totally because in the Preference section, and add-ons, ANT Landscape is there and selected but that's it.
What am I missing? Oh yeah! I'm not a stable genius.

Thank you for any help you could provide me with.

Comment: You mean when you go to add it, (`SHIFT+A > Mesh > Landscape`), nothing happens?

Comment: SHIFT+A .> MEsh > ?Landscape is no longer there. I'm gonna uninstall and reinstall.Thanks!